# Remoting in Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, rmi, remoting

I've got existing Play application, I need to add to it remoting capacities.

RMI would be ideal choose, since I don't need to rewrite original client application. It's possible to run rmi registry myself, but I would like to avoid it. In EJB container rmi registry starts itself.

Another option - is to use `Hessian` for example, but in this case I need to add special servlet  mapping in `web.xml` Is it possible to do it in Play ?

Or I can use web-services, but it's more like overkill in my situation. And again I need to add mapping in `web.xml` for Axis of CXF for example.

Could you suggest fastest and easiest way to add remoting for play application ?

Comment: I would like to know how to use Hessian specifically as well, and unfortunately the current answer simply says REST, but that's not really the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play provides a library ([WS](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/libs#WebServiceclient)) which makes it very easy to connect with 3rd party apps via HTTP requests. That would be your best bet if you can add a REST layer to the remote application.

If not, you could try to use RMI and run play within a Java EE container as a war file (to get access to container), but that will hinder the normal developemnt flow.

Choosing one or the other may depend on the effort involved to add that REST layer. If it's not too complex, I would favour that.

Comment: 3rd part library should connect play, not vise versa. So if I run play within container I can get access to web.xml for example ?

Comment: Yes, if you package it as war you'll have your web.xml, although if Play is the accessed app, better to create a REST interface in Play (quite easy) and call it from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just use REST json services, you have everything in play to do so, nothing else is needed

Comment: I know about REST json services, it's not best choice.